# Bootstrapテンプレートで、<select class="form-control"> の角丸を四角にしたい

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<select class="form-control" style="border-radius: 0!important;">
```

を指定しました。

MacのFirefoxでは四角になりましたが、MacのChromeでは角丸のままで変化がありませんでした。

知ってらっしゃる方、方法など教えてください。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 1):

`-webkit-appearance:none;` を指定してください。

```
<select class="form-control" style="border-radius: 0!important; -webkit-appearance:none;">
```